# A single iterator of vectorS

Tags: c++, vector, stl, iterator

Is there an efficient way to have a single `iterator` iterate on the concatenation of 2 objects `vector`, as if they were one?

The two vectors contain the same data type of course.

UPDATE:

I think I should have put more details about my question and my context. This may answer some of the questions:

In fact I am having one attribute that store the last position of that iterator and inside one method I start to iterate from the last position where I stopped in the previous call, which might be in the first vector or in the second one.

Comment: When you reach the `end` on the first set the iterator to `begin` on the other? Or create a third vector containing all of the first two vectors.

Comment: Maybe stuff both vectors in your own "container" object and write your own custom iterator to enum them by holding an iterator in one(or the other) as well as a hint to indicate *which one*. Warning, things could get... busy... if you go full-random-access on your iterator tag.

Comment: It shouldn't be very hard to write one.

Comment: Is there anything wrong with using two `for` loops? `v1.begin()` -> `v1.end()`, then `v2.begin()` -> `v2.end()`? It would be easier to suggest something if you specified what do you want to do with it, or how would you like to interface with the solution.

Comment: @WhozCraig +1 for your solution. I guess this is the cleanest way although I think the solution suggested by KeillRandor can be fast with the addition of a boolean and a couple of ifs inside my for loops

Comment: the problem with Keil's solution is the conditional expression. Comparing two iterators *from different containers* may "work", but its UB. The iterator from A can't legally be compared against one from B, even B.end(). It may "work", (likely for vectors) but not because the standard supports it.

Comment: @luk32 I updated my solution to answer your question. thanks for your remark.

Comment: @WhozCraig I don't understand why you say is UB, since vectorA and vectorB are both vector<Whatever> and the iterator should be compatible. I tested the code before posting and it was OK, but if I'm overlooking something please tell me, I'm always willing to learn :)

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I updated my solution to answer your question. thanks for your remark.

Comment: @KeillRandor It isn't a type-thing (clearly they're the same *type*). It is a range-thing. C++11 24.2.1p6 and C++11 24.2.1p7 refer to what I am regarding, and though too lengthy to post here, the crux of it is an iterator of a sequence is value-comparable only to other "reachable" iterators of the *same* sequence. Your loop idea is a very good one; just a little massaging ([something like this](http://pastebin.com/DX1aiGL2)). It seems a little odd, but it is well-within standard.

Comment: @WhozCraig what do you think about the new solution I've just posted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about this solution? It may be not elegant, but I guess it respects the standard. right?

```
vector<Whatever>::iterator it = vectorA.begin();
bool loopOnVectorA = true;

while(true) {

  // My stuff here

  if (loopOnVectorA && it == vectorA.end())
  {
    it = vectorB.begin();
    loopOnVectorA = false;
  }
  else if (it == vectorB.end())
  {
    break;
  }
  else
  {
    varPtrIt++;
  }
}
```

Comment: It won't compile - `While`. If you want a review, make a working (preferably compilable) code and go to Code Review, they are good at telling what's good and bad in working codes.